# Image in li tag as part of a jquery carousel are first show before they are part of the carousel?

Tags: jquery, carousel

i have problem with roundabout.js in IE. In IE the images are first loaded as a typical ul list and then they are put in the jQuery carousel. Chrome will put the images straight into the jquery carousel.

How can i hide the images before the carousel is intialized or any other work around?

regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the images using `visibility` property.
In CSS

```
body{visibility:hidden;}
```

And then using jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: tx for your answer. I already tried a similar solution by hiding the carousel div and showing on ready. Not satisfied, i like to "feed the carosel" as soon as an image is loaded (Chrome seems to do that)

Comment: Okay. I thought you wanted to hide the images, not delay the image load. The worst part in IE is it dead slow in loading anything. Can't help it!

Comment: The only workaround would be to replace `img` with `body` and it's not gonna make any difference for chrome or FF. That way, you'll effectively see the carousel loaded along with images